# How to run Alamofire library

Tags: swift, alamofire

[image]I downloaded the alamofire library and opened the iOS Example.xcodeproj, but it won't run. 
In import Alamofire , when i command press it it gives message that Alamofire symbol not found. Alamofire.framework is showing red. How to tackle this problem?

[image]

Comment: Screenshot and errors dump would be appreciate :)

Comment: It is not working even the example file of Alamofire library.. Guys please help me

Comment: Have you tried removing the red files? And then adding them back in..

Comment: Can you try `var method: Method? = nil` just before the error please.

Comment: No, I just tried to run the example project given when I downloaded the Alamofire library, and just opened it to run and these red lines showed when i tried to run the example

Comment: What's your Xcode version?

Comment: hey VivienG when i did as you said,, error again shows,, screenshot is this url=> http://postimg.org/image/jl98bsn5r/,,

Comment: @ Scott my xcode version is 6

Comment: the main issue is that Alamofire.framework is showing red and when i control press Alamofire is showing symbol not found,,

Comment: It llook like someone had an error similar to yours [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25327168/default-initializer-in-swift)

Comment: Its not working,, can you tell me why framework is showing red,, may be this one is causing the trouble

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Any fixes for it yet?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

So I removed all files related to Alamofire from project folder and also removed the framework from the project.

Then I again added [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) framework as per its guide and that ran successfully.

I suggest you to do same.

EDIT: This is why is the framework is showing in [red color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365114/frameworks-are-red-in-xcode)

Comment: when i did as you have said,, there is nothing error but the project doesn't run,, this is the screenshot => http://postimg.org/image/4vconiznb/,, please suggest me. Also tell me why the Alamofire.framework is showing red,, is this causing trouble or not?

Comment: check this link for Why framework is showing red[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365114/frameworks-are-red-in-xcode]

Comment: Alamofire.request(.GET,"http://httpbin.org/get", parameters: ["foo":"bar"], encoding: .URL)
            .responseJSON {(request, response, data, error) in  I think You miss to add Encoding

Comment: but in xcode 6 how to set the default setting is Relative to Current SDK,, i moved to general tab but found no area to set, can you help me if you are using xcode6

Comment: i m really sorry but i haven't used it with xcode 6!

Comment: can you look if you have some time, what is happening i have zipped the sample project https://www.dropbox.com/s/gcmpwzdupj3gzrn/NetworkTest.zip?dl=0 and please make it runnable, i will greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: again just delete all the files of alamofire from project folder and also remove framework! open terminal and navigate it upto location of your project and just write this "git submodule add https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git" without "". And again add Alamofire.xcodeproject to your project and add framework to the project!

Comment: thapa-bimals-MacBook-Pro:Testingnetwork thapa_bimal$ git submodule add https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git
fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /Volumes/E)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set)

Comment: after cloning has finished, from where i have to add Alamofire.xcodeproject to my project,,

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16853624/git-discovery-across-filesystem-not-set

Comment: from your project folder!

Comment: i drag from my project to xcode, and tried to run but still got failed message, i put the breakpoint in the appdelegate also but the project never hit even appdelegate and show error when building project

Comment: tell me from starting , what actually do?

Comment: in xcode how to navigate to the target configuration window,, where is it? i am not seeing application target,, how to do it? can you be screen shot of the steps now onwards?

Comment: 1.terminal https://www.dropbox.com/s/8wuipz4hgwbxtid/Screen%20Shot%202014-10-22%20at%205.19.25%20pm.png?dl=0

Comment: Right click on NetworkTest(Your Project) add files to "NetworkTest" -->NetworkTest-->Alamofire-->Alamofire.xcodeproject

Comment: if you get error in terminal "/NetworkTest/Alamofire' already exists in the index" then just follow last step

Comment: after adding Alamofire.xcodeproject,, i am getting ? sign in all NetworkTest files,, whats wrong is happening

Comment: after adding Alamofire.xcodeproject how to select the application target under the "Targets" heading in the sidebar. where is the application target,, please provide me screen shot of it

Comment: when I add Target Dependencies to Alamofire.framework,, build failed,, if i delet it build succeed,, what is problem when i add Alamofire.framework in target dependencies

Comment: I am getting this error, how to avoid it? => Unable to run command 'Ld Alamofire' - this target might include its own product.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to go to the Build Phases and add the framework from there or you could use cocoa pods to make reference to Alamofire I already give an answer in how to install cocoa and add a Podfile to import different libraries into a project here is the link 
[Error: Importing Alamofire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31824691/error-importing-alamofire/32769387#32769387)

Hope it works any doubts, I'm here to help