# Xcode fails to archive app with Alamofire

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, build, alamofire

I can run my app in the simulator and on my device just fine. However, as soon as I try to archive the app (in order to upload it to iTunes Connect) the process fails.

`Could not build Objective-C module 'Alamofire'`

I have included Alamofire as a git submodule in my app. I have already submitted various betas to iTunes Connect and never encountered this problem before.

I did not change any build settings though. Any other idea what could be wrong ? The problem seems related to [this issue in github](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/248) but no solution was provided.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Several answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26834293/swift-could-not-build-objective-c-module-alamofire)

Comment: None of those helped. Still running in the simulator but failing to archive

Answer (score 0):

Do You use other modules with Alamofire in Your project?
If so the solution is adding a dependencies of Alamofire to other modules to, same as in main project.
Another solution could be Derived data from xCode. Go to your xCode project and clean all Derived data.