# Could not build Objective-C module 'zipzap'

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, cocoapods

I would like to use `zipzap` library in my swift ios project.

I use cocoapods to integrate it. When I run `pod install` everything works fine, but when I do `import zipzap`, it says `Could not build Objective-C module 'zipzap'`.

I've done everything that people recommend [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26834293/swift-could-not-build-objective-c-module-alamofire) and in similar questions. But no luck.

Is it possible that this library simply not compatible with swift-based projects?

This is my `Podfile`:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '6.0'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
use_frameworks!

target 'MyProject-iOS' do
pod 'Reachability', '~> 3.2'
pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 2.1'
pod 'zipzap', '~> 8.0'
end

target 'MyProject-iOSTests' do

end
```

Comment: do you get error on line including <new>? Cause that the issue I am facing.

Comment: I'm having a similar error. I've tried using an objective-c bridging header to link the framework but am getting an error on ZZDataProvider.h on line "#include<new>"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I faced the same issue. Looks like the podspec for zipzap is missing. Due to which pod ends up making all header files public. And that is what causes the issue.

I wrote my own podspec file which only makes five headers public, rest are private. This decision was based on the podspec.json found in the zipzap repo.

I included zipzap in my project as follows:

pod 'zipzap', :podspec => 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tahasamad/zipzap/master/zipzap.podspec'

Comment: I tried doing what you suggested but got the following: "[!] The platform of the target `Pods` (OS X 10.10) is not compatible with `zipzap (8.0.3)`, which does not support `osx`." I'm running mine on OSX, so the error makes sense, but when I kept pod 'zipzap': '~> 8.0.3" it ran, but then wouldn't let me import.

Comment: Strange -- the zipzap pod spec is definitely present but in JSON format. And the pod spec definitely only references the public headers: https://github.com/pixelglow/ZipZap/blob/master/ZipZap.podspec.json

Answer (score 4):

I'm the author of ZipZap. Version 8.0.4 now properly supports iOS and OS X frameworks, both with and without CocoaPods. After updating with CocoaPods, you should just be able to `import ZipZap` in Swift and "it just works".

In order to get correct exception handling, you'll have to use CocoaPods 0.36 or later, otherwise you may get some build warnings.

Comment: I had to use "import zipzap" (all lowercase) instead of "import ZipZap" (uppercase Zs). Using CocoaPods 0.38.2 and ZipZap 8.0.4