# Error: Importing Alamofire

Tags: alamofire

..Hi I'm having a hard time Importing Alamofire I've finished the tutorial but I got an error message in "import Alamofire" line 2.. what should I do??..In buid phases my Target Dependencies was "Alamofire iOS (Alamofire)" that was my only option together with the "Alamofire OSX (Alamofire)" no option for "Alamofire (Alamofire)" like in the tutorial..

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

class ViewController: UIViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://ec2-54-169-246-41.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com:3000", parameters: nil)
        .response { request, response, data, error in
            println(request)
            println(response)
            println(error)
      }
      // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
      super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
      // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }
}
```

Comment: Sometimes when you simply build the project it removes the error, have you given this a whirl?

Answer (score 2):

I had a lot of trouble with Alamofire when I tried to copy the project from git and add it to my project. my solution was "s60" comment to use CocoaPods, so here are the steps to using a Podfile:

First open your terminal and install CocoaPoads with the following command:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

After installation go to the folder of your app with the commands cd+"name of path" for example:

```
cd Documents
cd AlamofireProject
```

When you are inside your project folder use the next command:

```
pod init
```

After running this command a Podfile should be created in your directory you should open the Podfile and then specify the version of Alamofire that you want to use, the source of the Podfile and that you want to use frameworks in your app, here is how you Podfile should look

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'YOUR APP NAME' do
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 2.0'

end
```

After you edit your Podfile save it and then run this command in the terminal:

```
pod install
```

If everything runs smoothly now you should have in your app folder a new folder called Pods and a ".xcworkspace" file. Now you must work in the workspace file where you can reference the Alamofire library smoothly like this:

```
import Alamofire

    Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://omgvamp-hearthstone-v1.p.mashape.com/cards",parameters:["X-Mashape-Key:":"ibxqtnAb9BmshWhdS6Z4zttkVtQop1j0yGSjsn6tn5x2Y4BBF0"])
        .responseJSON { _, _, result in
            switch result {
            case .Success(let data):
                let json = JSON(data)
                debugPrint(data)
                self.Photos = self.ParseHS(json)
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("ToCollection", sender: self)
            case .Failure(_, let error):
                print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
            }

        }
```

This is a sample function of an Alamofire request that I use in one of my apps. If you have any trouble leave me a comment. XD Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

easiest way to integrate Alamofire is use CocoaPods

add below to your Podfile and run pod update Alamofire will auto integrated into your project

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'Alamofire', '~> 1.3.0
```

'

Answer (score -1):

Alamofire is very good networking library written in Swift. There are two ways to integrate Alamofire in project:

1. **Cocoa Pod:**
   To Add new `Alamofire` library to your current project go with the `pod installation`. below is the code you have to integrate in your pod file for fresh installation of Alamofire.

   ```
     source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
     platform :ios, '8.0'
     use_frameworks!

    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 2.0'
   ```

With the latest release of Alamofire 2.0 request method get change.

I am posting some sample steps which will help you most

Here is my sample code,
//Step:

```
    import Alamofire
```

// Step : 1

```
     var manager = Manager.sharedInstance
```

// Specifying the Headers we need

```
    manager.session.configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = [
    "Content-Type": "application/graphql",
    "Accept": "application/json" //Optional
    ]
```

// Step : 3 then call the Alamofire request method.

```
    Alamofire.request(.GET, url2).responseJSON { request, response,result in
    print(result.value)
    }
```

Try this or you can check the latest update from alamofire on xcode 7:

https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire

In previous version of Alamofire there is one more parameter for handle in request method, now that was removed. Check Git for more information. I think this will help you more.

2. **Mannual:**
   Download the Alamofire from git: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire , then extract the downloaded folder.

From your project -> `click on add files to "project"` -> navigate to extracted folder -> find `Alamofire.xcodeproj` -> select the `Alamofire.xcodeproj` file -> please make sure `Copy items if needed` is checked.

Now its time to add Alamofire into embedded binaries. To do that click on project name and then navigate to General tab -> select `Embedded Binaries` -> click on '+' -> now add `Alamofire.xcodeproj`.

Lastly use `import Alamofire` in .swift file, whenever you want to use Alamofire.

But my personal opinioin is, if you are using `Xcode 7` and `Swift 2` then you must go with the Cocoapod installation for `Alamofire`